# Rails .includes() returning 'undefined method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a Company object with an associated Location.

Company has_many :locations
Location belongs_to :company

When I call:

```
@company = Company.find(5).includes(:locations)
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<Company:0x000000066ad398>
```

I'm following the rubyonrails.org instructions to a T... as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 9):

`find()` triggers a database query, and returns an instance of the model. You can't call `includes` on it, as `includes` is supposed to have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` as receiver.

You need to invert the order: `find` **must** stay at the end:

```
@company = Company.includes(:locations).find(5)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am no longer getting the error, but I'm not getting :locations returned with the Company. (turning this response into json)

Comment: Then it must be a different issue. Please open a different question, as this specific error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the records in the database on `location.rb` model. The `company_id` is there?

You can use `pry-rails` in order to debug the code. Your code looks ok.

The json you are creating is with `jbuilder`? because is that the case, you need to create the corresponding each loop.